# Any simpler solution for this simple problem?

Tags: complex-numbers

The problem is: for complex number $z=re^{i\theta}$, derive an inequality between $r$ and $\theta$ such that $$|\cos(2z)|<1$$

In my solution, I found that if $z=a+bi$, then the following is satisfied: $$\cos(4a)<2-\cosh(4b)$$

However, when I substitute in $a=r\cos(\theta)$ and b=$r\sin(\theta)$, the inequality becomes extremely complicated.

Since the problem is so simple, I believe that there is a solution that is in the form $f(r)<g(\theta)$. But I failed to obtain it.

Could anyone give a simpler solution?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you define $\cos(z)$?

Comment: @Holo the complex cosine function. I can’t see any ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the complex $\cos$:
$$
2\cos(re^{i\theta}) =
(e^{2r\sin\theta} + e^{-2r\sin\theta})\cos(2r\cos(\theta)) + i\sin(2r\cos(\theta)),
$$
$$|\cos(re^{i\theta})| =
|\cosh({2r\sin\theta})|,
$$
And $\cosh$ is positive in $\Bbb R$ and $< 1$ in...